# MGTwitterEngine for Iphone SDK errors

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to get MGTwitterEngine to work for the iPhone SDK. I've followed the read me below and now I keep getting the following errors:

TCDownload.h: No such file or directory
yajl_parse.h: No such file or directory

Now, I've done a search on my system and don't have either one of them. So am I missing something? Also, I've downloaded the MGTwitterEngine code within the last couple days from gitub.

READ ME

1. Add libxml2.dylib in Other Frameworks. You'll find the library in:

   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS2.0.sdk/usr/lib/libxml2.dylib
2. Add "$SDKROOT/usr/include/libxml2" as a Header Search Path in your Project Settings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although I've never used MGTwitterEngine, that error basically says that you are missing yajl library.

You can install it manually by doing (I assume you install to default /usr/local location):

```
git clone git://github.com/lloyd/yajl
cd yajl
./configure
sudo make install
```

Then in your xcode project:

Add libyajl.dylib or libyajl_s.a (dynamic/static - whichever you prefer, either should be located in /usr/local/lib/) to 'external frameworks and libraries' in your project tree. In project settings add "/usr/local/include/yajl/" and (possibly) "/usr/local/include/" to Header Search Paths (in Search Paths section).

After that it should build.

Comment: I'm in the same bind. But trying git clone git://github.com/lloyd/yajl in terminal gave me this error "git: command not found". How do I make this work?

Comment: If you want to use yajl for iPhone development, you will have to take a further step to create the library for iPhone as well as MacOS X, which these instructions won't do.

Comment: RexOnRoids: you need to install git.

Comment: I can't find `external frameworks and libraries` in my project tree. `Frameworks` is there but then I don't see any option of how and where to add `libyajl.dylib`

Answer (score 3):

On mac, you can use port (See how to install [here](http://www.macports.org/install.php))

After install simply type in terminal :

> sudo port install yajl

And like ttvd say before:

In your xcode project:

Add libyajl.dylib or libyajl_s.a (dynamic/static - whichever you prefer, either should be located in /usr/local/lib/) to 'external frameworks and libraries' in your project tree. In project settings add "/usr/local/include/yajl/" and (possibly) "/usr/local/include/" to Header Search Paths (in Search Paths section).

Comment: Just a note that mac ports seemed to install into /opt/local/include rather than /usr/local/include for me

Answer (score 3):

This works if you don't care about YAJL:

"Guys – the yajl/yajl_parse.h error is confusing and the reason the demo works is that the files that need yajl are excluded from building, even though they’re in the project. To fix in your own project go into the MGTwitter folder via xcode and select each .m file with the term yajl in it (there should be 6), right-click -> Get Info -> Targets tab and uncheck the box next to your app name. HTH, Jon"

One of the comments on http://aralbalkan.com/3133

Answer (score 2):

I am just going to add something because I think it is important and I usually hacked around it in the past.

---->>
The header search paths are defined in project settings but are over-ridden in the target settings so if you are having problems including certain files check the header search paths that are set in your target settings.  If they are bold then they are being used and overriding the default settings for the project.

Answer (score 0):

dl and install this: http://cmake.org
before

git clone git://github.com/lloyd/yajl
cd yajl
./configure
sudo make install

then add the dylibs and you should be ok!