# How to setup MGTwitterEngine

Tags: iphone, xcode, installation, mgtwitterengine

Just downloaded from github ... tried to build the xcode project and got over a hundred errors.  TouchJSON, OAuthConsumer and yajl folders don't even exist (which looks like the problem).

Did I pooch something?  What do I need to do to recover?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its all in there so that you have many possible ways to consume the responses.  It is a pain in the butt to just grab and try to go if you don't know what to expect. The easiest way to get it all up and running (if you aren't going to use a third party library and simply use native xml parsing) is to simply remove the files that reference them.  Just delete any file that has "TouchJSON" or "YAJL" in it's filename.  You will have to get the OAuth lib since twitter is killing basic auth next month. Brad's post above has a link to that.  If you want to use the JSON versions, be sure to set the define statements YAJL_AVAILABLE or TOUCHJSON_AVAILABLE to 1 so that MGTwitterengine knows to use it.

Comment: Thanks.  As a side note ... If I'm already using the Three20 (which is using YAJL) ... do I have to include the YAJL lib again?

Comment: All answers and comments were helpful. In the end, I just went with the Twitter+Oauth solution by Ben Gottleib's solution here http://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone.  Didn't have to do anything with yajl as it was included in Three20.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install TouchJSON, and various other modules, like YAJL and oauthconsumer.  If you don't need YAJL, you need to remove the *yajl* files from your project.

MGTwitterEngine isn't a very clean install, it usually needs a lot of tweaking to get it to build properly.

Comment: "isn't a very clean install" is an understatement ... the simple steps it purports to be "all that you need" seems far from the truth. Where do I get TouchJSON, OAuthConsumer and yajl?  And once I have them ... what do I do with them to get the demo project working???  OR ... is there an easier way to tweet?  Thanks

Comment: @wgpubs - For YAJL, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338496/mgtwitterengine-for-iphone-sdk-errors/1338603#1338603.  TouchJSON can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/source/checkout and OAuthConsumer here: http://code.google.com/p/oauthconsumer/.  MGTwitterEngine gives you a lot for free, and there's a reason why it is used in so many applications.

Comment: Thanks Brad.  As I said below, was able to get all working nicely in my iPhone project using this drop-in code (http://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone).  As I was already using the Three20 framework in my project I didn't have to do anything with YAJL ... though I did follow the steps in the link you provided just in case I do need it at some point.